# Java applet Error ... What is wrong?

Tags: java, html, swing, japplet

**Java applet code**

```
package M257Applet

import java.applet.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class HellowApplet extends JApplet {

    public  void init(){

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        JLabel lb = new JLabel("Hellowwwww");
        cp.add(lb);
    }

}
```

**html file**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Applet</title>
</head>
<body>
<APPLET CODE = HellowApplet.class  WIDTH =  400   HEIGHT = 400 >
</APPLET>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error**

```
Java Plug-in 1.6.0_22
Using JRE version 1.6.0_22-b04 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\pc
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------


java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HellowApplet (wrong name: M257Applet/HellowApplet)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HellowApplet (wrong name: M257Applet/HellowApplet)
```

Comment: <html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


<APPLET CODE = "HellowApplet.class"  WIDTH =  400   HEIGHT = 400 >
</APPLET>

</body>
</html>

Comment: `JLabel("Hellowwwww");`  Note the word 'hello' does not have a 'w', let alone 4 of them!

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: "Hellowwwww" is an onomatopoetic echo and possibly the name of a band. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem is with the package. You need to change the code attribute of applet, and based on where you have placed your HTML, the codebase attribute too. You have to place HellowApplet.class in a directory called M257Applet (because that is the package you have given), and the applet tag should look something like:

```
<applet code="M257Applet.HellowApplet" ... ></applet>
```

For this to work, your HTML has to be in the same directory as M257Applet (not inside M257Applet). Alternatively, you can specify the codebase attribute. For eg, with the following directory structure:

```
somedir
  +-- hello.html
  +-- M257Applet
  |    +-- HellowApplet.class
```

the applet will work. If however, you had

```
anotherdir
  +-- hello.html
  +-- somedir
  |   +-- M257Applet
  |   |    +-- HellowApplet.class
```

then you will have to specify codebase attribute like so:

```
<applet code="M257Applet.HellowApplet" codebase="somedir" ... ></applet>
```

So, you should have `codebase` pointing to the directory containing your package, and `code` has to have your package name also in it.

Edit:
Please note, even though `code="HellowApplet.class"` will work, the correct way of specifying the applet is without the ".class" at the end.

Comment: Good description of the paths.  Note that the `code` attribute of `M257Applet.HellowApplet.class` should be the fully qualified name of the class, so  `M257Applet.HellowApplet`.  And of course taking into account common nomenclature & spelling - `m257applet.HelloApplet` ;)

Comment: `code="M257Applet.HellowApplet.class"` Should ideally be `code="M257Applet.HellowApplet"`.  It represents the fully qualified class name.  The 1st form is tolerated, but not correct.

Comment: @Raze - What if my class folders is 6 folders within the root, where would the extra folders go, within the codebase?

Comment: I didn't understand what exact structure you have @RyanSammut, but assuming you have defined the applet in package foo.bar, and you have it in the folder root/f1/f2/f3/f4/foo/bar/Applet.class and HTML in root/, your `codebase="f1/f2/f3/f4"` and `code="foo.bar.Applet"` also assuming your HTML file is directly in root.

Answer (score 3):

Your class is in a package. It's file name should match.

```
code="M257Applet/HellowApplet.class"
```

(It's a good idea to follow conventions. Package names should be all lower case.)