# How to run java .class applet in browser on localhost

Tags: java, jar, applet

I know nothing about Java **at all** and I only need to run an applet on browser in localhost.

I only download the `.class` file from the following website

http://isgwww.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/tspanner/TSpanner.html

and I need to run this `.class` file on my localhost.

I tried every solution given in [Java applet Error … What is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009767/java-applet-error-what-is-wrong) but I failed to run it.

This is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head>
 <title>Visualization of Spanners - The Applet</title>
</head>
<body alink="#990099" bgcolor="#cccccc" link="#000099" vlink="#000099">
<applet code="gsn.TSpanner" align="BOTTOM" height="480" width="720"></applet>
</body></html>
```

In the directory where this `.html` is placed, I created a folder and renamed it to `gsn` and copied `TSpanner.class` file in there, after going to the url of the `.html` file Java throws the following error

> #### NoClassDefFoundError
>
> gsn/TSpanner (wrond name:TSpanner)

I also tried copying `.class` file in the root directory and setting

```
<applet code="TSpanner.class" align="BOTTOM" height="480" width="720"></applet>
```

It didn't work again.

Is it possible to run this `.class` in localhost? There is no more files (like `.jar`) and if yes how?

Thanks.

Comment: The latest version of Chrome (which is what I'm using) doesn't even support Applets anymore.  Alas, my capacity to help you is very limited.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using Fire Fox and after updating Java Plugin it allowed me to run it.

Comment: I have a detailed solution for you, q.v. my answer below.  I used the `appletviewer` tool which ships with the Java JDK.  If you only have the JRE, then I would recommend that you [download the JDK here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this applet to run using the `appletviewer` command line tool which comes with the JDK.  The `appletviewer` tool expects you to feed it an HTML page containing an `<applet>` tag, so I created the following mock page for this purpose:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD><TITLE>Test Page</TITLE></HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <APPLET code="TSpanner.class" align="BOTTOM" height="480" width="720"></applet>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Save this HTML page in a directory somewhere and call it `test.html`.  You will be using this later with the `appletviewer` tool.

The trick to getting it to run was to download *all* the class files upon which `TSpanner.class` is dependent.  This meant downloading the following 5 class files:

- TSpanner$AnimateThread.class
- Path.class
- Sheet.class
- Point.class
- PointVector.class

I downloaded these files from my browser by typing in the URL which Java itself would use, running from your browser, to obtain the necessary files.  Here is a sample URL which I used to download the `Point.class` file:

```
http://isgwww.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/tspanner/Point.class
```

Do this for each of the five required class files (by simply changing the name of the class file at the end of the above URL), and save them into a directory at the *same* level as the `test.html` page which you created above.

Finally, you can run the Java `appletviewer` from the command line.  Change directories to the `bin` directory of your Java installation and then run the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\appletviewer.exe test.html
```

Once it launches, you will see the applet running in its own window.  Here is a screen capture of what it looked like running on my own machine:

[image]

You *could* try to get this applet to run in your Firefox browser, but unless you plan on putting this in your own webpage, `appletviewer` is probably the easier way to go.  As you probably figured out, most browsers are dropping support for the `<applet>` tag at this point.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I am downloading the `Java SE Development Kit 8u60`, the `windows 32-bit`  version. I will follow your solution and let you the results

Comment: One additional comment: When you run `appletviewer`, you will need to specify the _full_ location of `test.html`, wherever that might be.  I think you can figure this step out yourself actually, as it has nothing to do with Java per se.

Comment: Am I downloading the right software, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html ?

Comment: Yes, this is the right place.  Choose the appropriate download for your OS (Windows, Linux, Mac OSX).

Comment: Thanks you very much. it works perfectly. thanks again.

Comment: *"The `appletviewer` tool expects you to feed it an HTML page containing an `<applet>` tag,"*  The applet viewer will also accept a `.java` file as the argument (instead of a `.html`) so long as the applet source code file defines an applet element in a comment in the first part of the file.  You can see an example (of source code with an applet element in a code comment) in the [applet info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info)..

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for making this comment, Andrew.